# How to customize y-axis label in Vega Lite through format function

Tags: javascript, vega-lite, vega

Is there a way to customize the y-axis labels in which I can pass the value to a function to format how it gets displayed. I'm having trouble due to needing it to accommodate different languages (20+).

example:

In one country, one label point will be: $100

In another, the label point will be: 100$

This example is just using the dollar, but will also be supporting currency from other countries.

How can I achieve this?

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "width": "container",
  "height": 300,
  "data": {
    "name": "table",
    "values": [
      {
        "x": "Sun - 1",
        "y": -0.01,
        "c": "This Month (02/26/23 - 03/07/23)",
        "z": "01/01/23"
      },
      {
        "x": "Sun - 1",
        "y": -0.01,
        "c": "Last Month (01/01/23 - 02/04/23)",
        "z": "03/01/23"
      },
      {
        "x": "Mon - 1",
        "y": 0.18,
        "c": "This Month (02/26/23 - 03/07/23)",
        "z": "01/01/23"
      },
      {
        "x": "Mon - 1",
        "y": 0.7,
        "c": "Last Month (01/01/23 - 02/04/23)",
        "z": "03/01/23"
      },
      {
        "x": "Tue - 1",
        "y": 0.23,
        "c": "This Month (02/26/23 - 03/07/23)",
        "z": "01/01/23"
      },
      {
        "x": "Tue - 1",
        "y": 0.45,
        "c": "Last Month (01/01/23 - 02/04/23)",
        "z": "03/01/23"
      },
      {
        "x": "Wed - 1",
        "y": 0.21,
        "c": "This Month (02/26/23 - 03/07/23)",
        "z": "01/01/23"
      },
      {
        "x": "Wed - 1",
        "y": 0.11,
        "c": "Last Month (01/01/23 - 02/04/23)",
        "z": "03/01/23"
      },
      {
        "x": "Thu - 1",
        "y": 0.79,
        "c": "This Month (02/26/23 - 03/07/23)",
        "z": "01/01/23"
      },
      {
        "x": "Thu - 1",
        "y": 0.35,
        "c": "Last Month (01/01/23 - 02/04/23)",
        "z": "03/01/23"
      },
      {
        "x": "Fri - 1",
        "y": 0.82,
        "c": "This Month (02/26/23 - 03/07/23)",
        "z": "01/01/23"
      },
      {
        "x": "Fri - 1",
        "y": 0.28,
        "c": "Last Month (01/01/23 - 02/04/23)",
        "z": "03/01/23"
      },
      {
        "x": "Sat - 1",
        "y": 0,
        "c": "This Month (02/26/23 - 03/07/23)",
        "z": "01/01/23"
      },
      {
        "x": "Sat - 1",
        "y": -0.01,
        "c": "Last Month (01/01/23 - 02/04/23)",
        "z": "03/01/23"
      },
      {
        "x": "Sun - 2",
        "y": 0,
        "c": "This Month (02/26/23 - 03/07/23)",
        "z": "01/01/23"
      },
      {
        "x": "Sun - 2",
        "y": -0.01,
        "c": "Last Month (01/01/23 - 02/04/23)",
        "z": "03/01/23"
      },
      {
        "x": "Mon - 2",
        "y": 0.21,
        "c": "This Month (02/26/23 - 03/07/23)",
        "z": "01/01/23"
      },
      {
        "x": "Mon - 2",
        "y": 0.11,
        "c": "Last Month (01/01/23 - 02/04/23)",
        "z": "03/01/23"
      },
      {
        "x": "Tue - 2",
        "y": 0.18,
        "c": "This Month (02/26/23 - 03/07/23)",
        "z": "01/01/23"
      },
      {
        "x": "Tue - 2",
        "y": 0.7,
        "c": "Last Month (01/01/23 - 02/04/23)",
        "z": "03/01/23"
      },
      {
        "x": "Wed - 2",
        "y": 0.1,
        "c": "This Month (02/26/23 - 03/07/23)",
        "z": "01/01/23"
      },
      {
        "x": "Wed - 2",
        "y": 0.5,
        "c": "Last Month (01/01/23 - 02/04/23)",
        "z": "03/01/23"
      },
      {
        "x": "Thu - 2",
        "y": 0.58,
        "c": "This Month (02/26/23 - 03/07/23)",
        "z": "01/01/23"
      },
      {
        "x": "Thu - 2",
        "y": 0.2,
        "c": "Last Month (01/01/23 - 02/04/23)",
        "z": "03/01/23"
      },
      {
        "x": "Fri - 2",
        "y": 0.23,
        "c": "This Month (02/26/23 - 03/07/23)",
        "z": "01/01/23"
      },
      {
        "x": "Fri - 2",
        "y": -0.01,
        "c": "Last Month (01/01/23 - 02/04/23)",
        "z": "03/01/23"
      },
      {
        "x": "Sat - 2",
        "y": -0.01,
        "c": "This Month (02/26/23 - 03/07/23)",
        "z": "01/01/23"
      },
      {
        "x": "Sat - 2",
        "y": -0.01,
        "c": "Last Month (01/01/23 - 02/04/23)",
        "z": "03/01/23"
      },
      {
        "x": "Sun - 3",
        "y": -0.01,
        "c": "This Month (02/26/23 - 03/07/23)",
        "z": "01/01/23"
      },
      {
        "x": "Sun - 3",
        "y": -0.01,
        "c": "Last Month (01/01/23 - 02/04/23)",
        "z": "03/01/23"
      },
      {
        "x": "Mon - 3",
        "y": 0.82,
        "c": "This Month (02/26/23 - 03/07/23)",
        "z": "01/01/23"
      },
      {
        "x": "Mon - 3",
        "y": -0.01,
        "c": "Last Month (01/01/23 - 02/04/23)",
        "z": "03/01/23"
      },
      {
        "x": "Tue - 3",
        "y": 0.82,
        "c": "This Month (02/26/23 - 03/07/23)",
        "z": "01/01/23"
      },
      {
        "x": "Tue - 3",
        "y": -0.01,
        "c": "Last Month (01/01/23 - 02/04/23)",
        "z": "03/01/23"
      },
      {
        "x": "Wed - 3",
        "y": 0.82,
        "c": "This Month (02/26/23 - 03/07/23)",
        "z": "01/01/23"
      },
      {
        "x": "Wed - 3",
        "y": -0.01,
        "c": "Last Month (01/01/23 - 02/04/23)",
        "z": "03/01/23"
      },
      {
        "x": "Thu - 3",
        "y": 0.21,
        "c": "This Month (02/26/23 - 03/07/23)",
        "z": "01/01/23"
      },
      {
        "x": "Thu - 3",
        "c": "Last Month (01/01/23 - 02/04/23)",
        "z": "03/01/23",
        "y": -0.01
      },
      {
        "x": "Fri - 3",
        "y": 0.18,
        "c": "This Month (02/26/23 - 03/07/23)",
        "z": "01/01/23"
      },
      {
        "x": "Fri - 3",
        "c": "Last Month (01/01/23 - 02/04/23)",
        "z": "03/01/23",
        "y": -0.01
      },
      {
        "x": "Sat - 3",
        "y": -0.01,
        "c": "This Month (02/26/23 - 03/07/23)",
        "z": "01/01/23"
      },
      {
        "x": "Sat - 3",
        "c": "Last Month (01/01/23 - 02/04/23)",
        "z": "03/01/23",
        "y": -0.01
      },
      {
        "x": "Sun - 4",
        "y": -0.01,
        "c": "This Month (02/26/23 - 03/07/23)",
        "z": "01/01/23"
      },
      {
        "x": "Sun - 4",
        "c": "Last Month (01/01/23 - 02/04/23)",
        "z": "03/01/23",
        "y": -0.01
      },
      {
        "x": "Mon - 4",
        "y": 0.23,
        "c": "This Month (02/26/23 - 03/07/23)",
        "z": "01/01/23"
      },
      {
        "x": "Mon - 4",
        "c": "Last Month (01/01/23 - 02/04/23)",
        "z": "03/01/23",
        "y": -0.01
      },
      {
        "x": "Tue - 4",
        "y": 0.21,
        "c": "This Month (02/26/23 - 03/07/23)",
        "z": "01/01/23"
      },
      {
        "x": "Tue - 4",
        "c": "Last Month (01/01/23 - 02/04/23)",
        "z": "03/01/23",
        "y": -0.01
      },
      {
        "x": "Wed - 4",
        "y": 0.79,
        "c": "This Month (02/26/23 - 03/07/23)",
        "z": "01/01/23"
      },
      {
        "x": "Wed - 4",
        "c": "Last Month (01/01/23 - 02/04/23)",
        "z": "03/01/23",
        "y": -0.01
      },
      {
        "x": "Thu - 4",
        "y": 0.82,
        "c": "This Month (02/26/23 - 03/07/23)",
        "z": "01/01/23"
      },
      {
        "x": "Thu - 4",
        "c": "Last Month (01/01/23 - 02/04/23)",
        "z": "03/01/23",
        "y": -0.01
      },
      {
        "x": "Fri - 4",
        "y": 0.82,
        "c": "This Month (02/26/23 - 03/07/23)",
        "z": "01/01/23"
      },
      {
        "x": "Fri - 4",
        "c": "Last Month (01/01/23 - 02/04/23)",
        "z": "03/01/23",
        "y": -0.01
      },
      {
        "x": "Sat - 4",
        "y": -0.01,
        "c": "This Month (02/26/23 - 03/07/23)",
        "z": "01/01/23"
      },
      {
        "x": "Sat - 4",
        "c": "Last Month (01/01/23 - 02/04/23)",
        "z": "03/01/23",
        "y": -0.01
      },
      {
        "x": "Sun - 5",
        "y": -0.01,
        "c": "This Month (02/26/23 - 03/07/23)",
        "z": "01/01/23"
      },
      {
        "x": "Sun - 5",
        "c": "Last Month (01/01/23 - 02/04/23)",
        "z": "03/01/23",
        "y": -0.01
      },
      {
        "x": "Mon - 5",
        "y": 0.18,
        "c": "This Month (02/26/23 - 03/07/23)",
        "z": "01/01/23"
      },
      {
        "x": "Mon - 5",
        "c": "Last Month (01/01/23 - 02/04/23)",
        "z": "03/01/23",
        "y": -0.01
      },
      {
        "x": "Tue - 5",
        "y": 0.18,
        "c": "This Month (02/26/23 - 03/07/23)",
        "z": "01/01/23"
      },
      {
        "x": "Tue - 5",
        "c": "Last Month (01/01/23 - 02/04/23)",
        "z": "03/01/23",
        "y": -0.01
      },
      {
        "x": "Wed - 5",
        "y": 0.18,
        "c": "This Month (02/26/23 - 03/07/23)",
        "z": "01/01/23"
      },
      {
        "x": "Wed - 5",
        "c": "Last Month (01/01/23 - 02/04/23)",
        "z": "03/01/23",
        "y": -0.01
      },
      {
        "x": "Thu - 5",
        "y": 0.18,
        "c": "This Month (02/26/23 - 03/07/23)",
        "z": "01/01/23"
      },
      {
        "x": "Thu - 5",
        "c": "Last Month (01/01/23 - 02/04/23)",
        "z": "03/01/23",
        "y": -0.01
      },
      {
        "x": "Fri - 5",
        "y": 0.18,
        "c": "This Month (02/26/23 - 03/07/23)",
        "z": "01/01/23"
      },
      {
        "x": "Fri - 5",
        "c": "Last Month (01/01/23 - 02/04/23)",
        "z": "03/01/23",
        "y": -0.01
      },
      {
        "x": "Sat - 5",
        "y": -0.01,
        "c": "This Month (02/26/23 - 03/07/23)",
        "z": "01/01/23"
      },
      {"x": "Sat - 5", "c": "Last Month (01/01/23 - 02/04/23)", "y": -0.01}
    ]
  },
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "x", "axis": {"labelAngle": 270}, "title": "", "sort": null},
    "opacity": {"value": 0.5}
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "encoding": {
        "color": {
          "field": "c",
          "type": "nominal",
          "title": "",
          "scale": {"range": ["#CC3EBE", "#5E5782"]},
          "legend": {"orient": "top-left"},
          "sort": {"field": "x", "order": "ascending"}
        },
        "y": {
          "field": "y",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "title": "",
          "scale": {"domain": [0, 1]},
          "axis": {"labelExpr": "'$' + datum.value", "values": [0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1]},
          "stack": null
        },
        "xOffset": {"field": "c"}
      },
      "layer": [
        {"mark": {"type": "bar", "width": {"band": 1}, "align": "center"}},
        {
          "transform": [{"filter": {"param": "hover", "empty": false}}],
          "mark": {"type": "bar", "width": {"band": 1}, "align": "center"}
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "transform": [
        {"calculate": "datum.y >= 0 ? datum.y : -1", "as": "y"},
        {"pivot": "c", "value": "y", "groupby": ["x"]}
      ],
      "mark": "rule",
      "encoding": {
        "opacity": {
          "condition": {"value": 0.3, "param": "hover", "empty": false},
          "value": 0
        },
        "tooltip": [
          {
            "field": "This Month (02/26/23 - 03/07/23)",
            "type": "nominal",
            "title": "This Month"
          },
          {
            "field": "Last Month (01/01/23 - 02/04/23)",
            "type": "nominal",
            "title": "Last Month"
          }
        ]
      },
      "params": [
        {
          "name": "hover",
          "select": {
            "type": "point",
            "fields": ["x"],
            "nearest": true,
            "on": "mouseover",
            "clear": "mouseout"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

[editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAdxoATemhBQ5mJDVlwATooxwaZLGgDMABltK1SPWlCykCOFr1NBXpcRIggxwEGgA2qAAHloAygyyAAT8iQCMpgCeaPy2lLapSlBaACowNBCJALK6MIkAFLYATASNAGwt1smJttYEtgDsHQCUpgBeWvl9qR0gAL4K0XEJXelKWag5eQXaWgAySBCYVTX1k5ONnSlNfQAsw2MTvefWcwsgMejVSSmrIOu5qQAHIUSmUKl96Kdmm0Ol0en1BhcRkpxugztMLq9Fp85CtMmhcv0Qeh9odjrJIQ1ps84c1bHckQ80U8MS95tiQMUQni1gTKBdiZyweTKdcYRc4U9EdZkSBUSB0TN2e8StyfvjULkbmJBaSjhDalSprCrnSGTKmQqWUq3h8QAB1OBqHl-PmNbZFdClcoiw1i9oSq5S+4oibU1lYlXoR3O9W8zWUVIevYHfUnI00023ENyx7GzHKu2lBgu-6UfoATkF3vB6f9Ju6wcZobR4ZtHOLpb51h1OxJqd9pzbge6Zpz8vhz0jdoAYkYaF2E4DGtXhQaoS0A5dGwjx2H82zbVo5wu466E41gX2QHrBxnWbTs83c8yD9O4s5Fw5rzW7-WR5O0qyhOw6HhysSfme6ybPkuoDuu94Ntc9J7q+U6Fks3yJI0Grfp6Qo+gh-7boBqEKqB77oPEWE4fGMHJv2ZJEaBj4oc+E7WgWR44jRuH8gxBG1hSfrQlukq7ux+7odxIBfF0tHngCAm3sxB6seawF5tJHZqthfFAquhF1qJSFNhaLbkW+GFerpCllkS14qXWLFZmx5kvlaVkyTG8n6YZQmiiZAFmZprZeRyPkpHZfK9vhTnCUOamuRplqThG1lCiWUV8WIV74b+RFBSRIWpRRGWdtl8a5Cujnwc5SWjk+7kceFUYgCevlVfy1j+X+RXiQMZGKlxHIdZV570XBTH1ZmjVuaFnnaW1EFHON0G5LBP5rsZm6mRJzVSelMkrZ1E0bcpdUJYhAFjpJaFHeBywpC8dHnb1hW7cF+0LcNYHLU9iQvWdWxTWmV2-epQ2cX9dpyc9fHLu9O3isV32la1sO4vDr0g7V03gy5c0pRZaXtm1XJwF0QNlojW1GeD-VBmjJNlTJFNUxqk142DoqE8hxMeaTI1tZFgMIzV+XbQzn2o4Nd2WUtdqi9T2Rvdzf587dB33WTRaMBzXXukj0sowNQHo4roJZWLoMaw1-NQ2+OP5BlY024piZ5aC9OBTLZtDazo3zgb6uqbNDvy0LKsbOdGUndjwObZLPsiX7TNy9rCsPctkHu3Fl28-bWs-dDnOx8dAM3GXuPJwFqem+n5ssxjmFdFXtthw+yWO1OzupBlcOJO3HsCnTdcbg3O4Zz9gdtYPw-5-jhfh8XqWl335W6cPZZG2PfVp1PTeC7PRZb6Yi8836mtNSXTuJ-33lOm3fGVsbvuT6Rkcn1oosLymS9XyLjfNed91pbHKvrFI28+S01rvvD+JVm6Wy9JAoe59-6X0SivYBJN1731dsHKB4s371zEo3AOLd0Buz-oxTB10SKr1waA1W4Djq52gTHGu3tx4NEZofChyCQDxzQR3GaXciY9wjBvCuWExDVyTtw+BZD+Ff0oUIgGcjREEyAfNEBvd8EyUHpoj2Bk94fQQczY+aijHoNoXbbBuimH6LAS7NmuljFllMXA8xyjP6Z1+pRTk7jbE3gLoAhxAsWrOJYa4iKT8UgeL5F4xRPi9rTwttnJW8TEjGIvvY8REd-F4JcQ-DsqDEkJmSSglOE9fGIKsYIiqOSQnxWXgUxhgtikxNKW1N2FSARe2qTw4i-tVGCL6S0sJWD2k4M6cwzhsSc6rWaX3EhtS0lHxAmo4RuSMH5KQh0kpswAC68wQBwFkDoNQBgyCuCjKAAAZjQOAgg1BaBiEoJAURyh3MEEgJgLyACCsgyB+DQI0fotgzmYDoGC9ApgZBGEwGgWQDBBCCDOWwHASAoB0HWKAQIwQvAJjELMM5fyMjGAiKAC5Vybl3J0IINgJhUCPOea8rQRQlCYAyDgYlIBZBsAQAYIIpgYWYDhSABFUAgjEtAEYJAILiXhBAAAYgAMLqusAAUQAELatMKqsQ2qxD9GXCAU5Sg-BkAuW81lIBmXPIpN4LFQg4APORWcxFyL7VPJeXalUShmVqCpegA4UBbX0rJfGNl-qtBZG5by-lABHBgirxXOBoKQMVsL+XStlXctQQr9DyFQOEBwqRLUgC+T8+1fyAWCG1VEHALKQAAHIwBtsSAAakSE4TADAECUEJSEUwI7QgRAcNVHUuQZ3lh1JWr1egoAAGsUVooxUoKIAB5B5DyIBwB9bGjl6AijRpABS0NkQQDICMGu+1PK+VaCYEgEwShVAaBgHcl9sg7UP2rcIMgpbtAXMwFS6NoBMAKtkBAB5zKEDUpAE8wQYGWWgGxQqhD6AYBsFIG+85CAcA8rQA8oIB6yXHKULe+9kGk3PtfaYD9mh7U-r-WcoIFhgMRopOBk5yooOKtg-BxDMrBBQDRc4fl-bB2UAyIkAAfAAXm6IkAA-H25wMm5OoGSL8A48bIw4CzWwH1OwAhBFHegBNIAyBGDYAwHATB1gqpiKcyjN7X33pAEYNF-hzmXLYNckFdysU4rxQyuQ1yYVyDueO7sSgMMeC0DhvDphEBEfWKRwQ5HzNEoJNCtgbAUM0BwIhv1J7BJKI2TmR9-LBXCvcIIHNEr+UFRqJGcrAbWnhJmY4kAtWtD1ZFU17lua9kGjmFWxLCAwhlrcB4flKWqVKAPX4KAR7+t0fQDgNgBhkVKE67NlzFqlCGFfaEH1UGQhBuAwgezB7cPLe0H4Bj6A7sMAewwT1fHTlAA)

I've went through the documentation and through examples and can't find a solution.

Comment: I suggest you add the currency as the axis title instead of having complex logic which will have a negative impact on the data.